# count occurences in 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, count, aggregate-functions

I have a table called tasks (id, date, id_user ).
I have an other table called calendar (id, date ).
to find the number of occurrences of the date field for a user between 2 dates I use the query  :

```
$test1 = date(Y-m-d', strtotime('-7'));
$test2 = date('Y-m-d');
$query= $connect->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS counter FROM tasks WHERE matricule ='".$_SESSION['matricule']."' AND date < '".$test2."' AND date >= '".$test1."' GROUP BY date");
```

This query works.
I also want to display 0 for dates that are not in my table tasks but are in the table calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count the daily tasks performed by a given user over a range of days, including the days without tasks.

If you have a calendar table - say `calendar(dt)`, where `dt` is a `date` - you can do:

```
select c.dt, count(t.date) as counter
from calendar c
left join tasks t 
    on  t.matricule = :matricule
    and t.date = c.dt
where c.date >= :start_date and c.date < :end_date
group by c.dt
```

`:matricule`, `:start_date` and `:end_date` are *parameters* to the query; you should really be using prepared statements instead of concatenating POSTed values in the query string, which opens up your code to SQL injection.

If the time range always is the last week:

```
where c.date >= current_date - interval 7 day and c.date < current_date
```

Note how the aggregation differs from your original code: columns in the `select` clause are repeated in the `group by` clause (left apart those that are aggregated).